# what is the best way to handle the IllegalArgumentException("You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity") in glide?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

My app crashes sometimes and the exception that comes up in the logs is:

```
llegalArgumentException("You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity")
```

Given that i dont want my application to crash  , what are the possible workaround?
Should i modify the library code or catch the Exception
In Library(`RequestManagerRetriever.java`) :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private static void assertNotDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 && activity.isDestroyed()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity");
    }
}
```

Comment: can't you fix the cause: "you cannot start a load for a destroyed activity" ?

Comment: Can you please show the code so we can all examine it and see where you might be causing this exception?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to not "start a load for a destroyed activity".